# A Question About Multivariate Differentiation

Tags: calculus

I am stuck on a practice problem which involves the multivariable chain rule I think.

$$F \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$$ $$g \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$$

$$ F(x,y) := (g(x, g(x, y)), g(g(x, y), y))$$

Show that $F$ is differentiable and find the derivative.

It seems as though this might involve the chain rule, but I'm not sure. Perhaps it involves the definition of a derivative.

Any help would be appreciated, and like I mentioned this isn't homework, just a practice problem.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to suppose that $g$ is differentiable. Then you're right, this is a chain rule question. To clear things up, you might define $h: \Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2,(x,y)\mapsto (x,g(x,y))$ and similarly $k$ so that $F$ becomes $(g\circ h,g\circ k)$. Now you may be able to see that $F$ is differentiable since each of its coordinate functions is a composition of two differentiable functions ($h$ and $k$ are differentiable in turn because each of *their* coordinate functions is differentiable.)

Then in the simplest but least detailed notation, which assumes that you're comfortable with the chain rule, we get $DF=(Dg\circ Dh,Dg\circ Dk)$.

Let's flesh this out more concretely. $h'_{(x,y)}=\left(\begin{matrix} 1&0\\g_1(x,y)&g_2(x,y)\end{matrix}\right)$ where $g_1=\partial g/\partial x$ and similarly for $g_2$. In the same way we get $k'.$ Meanwhile we have to evaluate $g'$ at $h(x,y)$ to satisfy the chain rule, so we use $g'(h(x,y))=(g_1(x,g(x,y)), g_2(x,g(x,y))$ to compute $$Dg\circ Dh=(g_1(x,g(x,y))+g_2(x,g(x,y))g_1(x,y),g_2(x,g(x,y))g_2(x,y))$$ 
by matrix multiplication. You can get $F_2=Dg\circ Dk$ in the same way.

One more point: someone else, maybe a classmate of yours, posted a similar question that supposes $g$ is continuous. That's not enough: say $g(x,y)=|x|$. Then we'd have $F(x,y)=(|x|,|x|)$, which isn't differentiable.

Comment: Sorry, the only thing is I'm actually not comfortable using the multivariate chain rule. Is this a problem where I have to use partial derivatives? Also, is Dg of Dh equivalent to (g of h)'? Finally, if that's the case I'm a little confused because, for example, if F(x,y) = (sin 2x, sin 2x), we can't just use the chain rule and say F'(x,y) = (2 cos x, 2 cos x), right? Thanks again.

Comment: As I said, the notation is rather abstract. I'll add a concrete description that'll hopefully be more familiar to you.

Comment: Thanks, that clarified things. Just one more question: in the final derivative of F, which I think is a 2 x 2 matrix, the first coordinate of F (sub) 1 is the matrix entry at (1,  1) and the second coordinate of F (sub) 1 is the matrix entry at (1, 2), correct? In other words, F (sub) 1 is the "top" of the derivative matrix and F (sub) 2 is the bottom, correct? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for the delay-that's right.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  you need $g$ to be differentiable, not just continuous.  Then it is an application of the chain rule.  Let $g_x(x,y)=\frac {\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}$ and $g_y(x,y)=\frac {\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}$ and similarly for $F$.  Then the first coordinate of $F_x$ is $\frac {\partial g(x,g(x,y))}{\partial x}=g_x(x,g(x,y))+g_y(x,g(x,y))g_x(x,y)$